# join pivot data in query (Many To Many Polymorphic Relations)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5

I have Many To Many Polymorphic Relations.

```
post morphedByMany(postA)
post morphedByMany(postB)
post morphedByMany(postC)
```

---

```
postA morphToMany(post)
postB morphToMany(post)
postC morphToMany(post)
```

I have an array of postA and postC sort by 'updated_at' i got this array by using this:

`$Post::has('postB','<','1')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();`

now, i whant to know the type of each element without ruin theorder of the array. i want to do someting like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @if($post is postA)
        {{"post a"}}
    @elseif($post is postC)
         {{"post c"}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

for that I thought it can be done by getting the data of my pivot table Chained to post object and then I can check the type property.